# I need to increase value of my variabele x if the input is checked , then alert total x

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building up a quiz app in javascript only, I want to make the final step which calculates the final score. I have 2 var : `myl` & `score` : `myl` = DOM.checked of my input, `score` = 0.

I need to make it this way:

```
 if(myl.checked == True) {
  score += 1 
 }
```

Then I'd like to print the total score in the div, but every time I try to get the total  score I get only = 1 and the value of score didn't increased. Can any one help me please

I tried to set `score`  = 0 and `myl` = DOM.checked and put

`if(dom.checked == true) { score += 1}` then DOM.innerHTML = score

```js
function myFunction() {
      var myl = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      var myl1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
      var myl2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
      var myl3 = document.getElementById("myCheck3");
      var myscore = 0;

      if (myl.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      } else if (myl1.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1 ;
      } else if (myl2.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      } else if (myl3.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      }    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myscore;
    }
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3">

<button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck Checkbox</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">check</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I always get 1 as result of score,  not the total of correct or chosen inputs which should be 4

Comment: please note check() and uncheck() is extra useless  dead code don't need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set (var myscore = 0) outside of the function

Refactor JS portion below the way you want or build on top of it

The for loop checks to see if the checkbox is true or false - with each time adding +1. That sum is added to a variable and pushed back to the DOM.

Codepen Demo: https://codepen.io/aystarz52/pen/JQVzKz?editors=1111

**HTML**

```html
Check what applies to you: <br />
<label>Are you a boy?<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"></label><br />
<label>Are you a girl?<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1"></label><br />
<label>Are you a car?<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2"></label><br />
<label>Are you a dog?<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3"></label><br />

<hr />
<label><button class="checks" onclick="checks()">Check Checkbox</button></label>
<div id="answered"></div>
<label><button class="unchecked" onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck Checkbox</button></label>
<div id="missed"></div>
<label><button class="finalscore" onclick="myFunction()">Final Score</button></label>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Style**

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
var myscore = 0;
var missed = 0;
var answered = 0;

var myl = document.getElementById("myCheck");
var myl1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
var myl2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
var myl3 = document.getElementById("myCheck3");

var array1 = [myl, myl1, myl2, myl3];

function myFunction() {

  for (i=0;i<=array1.length;i++) {
    if (array1[i].checked == true) {
      myscore += 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You scored " + myscore + " Out Of 4";
    document.querySelector(".finalscore").className += " hide";
  }
}

function checks() {

  for (i=0;i<=array1.length;i++) {
    if (array1[i].checked == true) {
      answered += 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("answered").innerHTML = "You answered " + answered + " Out Of 4";
    document.querySelector(".checks").className += " hide";
  }
}

function uncheck() {

  for (i=0;i<=array1.length;i++) {
    if (array1[i].checked == false) {
      missed += 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("missed").innerHTML = "You missed " + missed + " Out Of 4";
    document.querySelector(".unchecked").className += " hide";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `myscore` is declared inside `myFunction()` so it always start at 0 and plus 1 when a checkbox checked. Move it outside the function will solve it.

Or if you just want to get the amount of checked checkbox, `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length` may help.

Demo:

```js
var myscore = 0;
function myFunction() {
      var myl = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      var myl1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
      var myl2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
      var myl3 = document.getElementById("myCheck3");

      if (myl.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      } else if (myl1.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1 ;
      } else if (myl2.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      } else if (myl3.checked == true) {
        myscore += 1;
      }    
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myscore;
    }
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3">

<button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck Checkbox</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">check</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo1"></div>
```